# Display percentage symbol next to the GridViewDataTextColumn

Tags: devexpress

I want to display the percentage symbol (%) next to the `GridViewDataTextColumn` in EditForm. I try to use `DisplayFormat.FormatString="p"` in `PropertiesTextEdit` but it does not work. It shows the percentage symbol inside the `TextBox` after the value typed. I.e If I type 50 it shows 5000.00%.
I want the symbol next to the `TextBox` or else inside the `TextBox` with correct typed value. I.e if I type 10 means it should display 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent numeric format specifier multiplies a number by 100. If you want to add the percentage symbol without multiplying a number then you can directly add this symbol to your format string and add escape character ("\") before it.
Here is example:

```
DisplayFormat.FormatString = "#0.00\\%"
```

Comment: I need a space between the value and the percentage(%) symbol. How to do that?

Comment: @mohamedsami If you need a space than add a space: `"#0.00 \\%"`.

Comment: Ok nempo, It works fine in EditForm but i want to display the same value in Grid. It doesn't work on grid. i type 10 means it shows 10.00% in textbox, that's fine. when i update the value it shows 1,000.00% on Grid. How to fix this?

Comment: I got it ...  DisplayFormatString="{0}%" Thank you nempo.